# Binding issue with groupedview Windows 8 App XAML/C#

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, groupstyle

A time ago I have asked how to implement a GroupedView and it worked quiet well, but now I have a problem. In my new App, the Grouped view only shows the GroupHeadings, but not the elements.
The MainViewModel has an ObservableCollection Playlists and every T has an ObservableCollection TopVideos.

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Playlists}"
                        IsSourceGrouped="True"
                        ItemsPath="TopVideos"
                        x:Name="GroupedCollection"/>
</Page.Resources>
<GridView x:Name="mainGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedCollection}}" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard250x250ItemTemplate}"
              Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1"
         LayoutUpdated="mainGridView_LayoutUpdated" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
```

This is nearly exact the code as in the answer to my question, but it does not work as expected. Has anyone an idea what I could have made wrong or how I can debug this problem better? Thanks for every answer.I am thankfull for every hint.